# Change "data-icon" dynamicly doesn't work

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

According to myself, this should work.... Trying to change icon on a **list view** item inside a collapsible / collapsible-set

```
var p = $("#mySet li[data-item='"+ item + "'][data-bin='"+ bin + "']").attr("data-icon");
```

If I alert(p), i get **"carat-r"**, wich is the icon.

But applying this does nothing:

```
$("#mySet li[data-item='"+ item + "'][data-bin='"+ bin + "']").attr("data-icon", "check");
```

Any ideas?

**Update**: The markup changes, actually (using firebug), so there seems to be some refresh issue?

**Update 2, thanks to Omar - Works now!**

```
$("#mySet li[data-item='"+ item + "'][data-bin='"+ bin + "'] a").removeClass("ui-icon").addClass("ui-icon-check");
```

Comment: Add `ui-icon-check` directly to anchor within li. `$("li a").addClass("ui-icon-check");`.

Comment: Have you tried calling $( "#mySet" ).listview( "refresh" ); after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List view items accommodate `<a>` tags which hold icons. `data-icon` attribute is deprecated and replaced with *icon* classes to be added directly into `<a>` tags.

However, in list view items, *icon* classes are added once list view is created. To change *icon* of a `li`, you need to add it directly into `li`'s anchor.

```
$("li a").addClass("ui-icon-check");
```

Moreover, you need to remove previous *icon*'s class. It can be done programmatically this way.

```
$(".selector a").removeClass(function (i, uiClass) {
  return (uiClass.match(/\bui-icon-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
}).addClass("ui-icon-check");
```

This will remove current *icon* and replaces it with `ui-icon-check`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/d27U7/)**